# Highcharts full circle gauge as in Knob js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-knob

Is there any simple example (preferibly with a JSFiddle) for an implementation of a full circle gauge with Highcharts like the one below from [jQuery knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) ?

[image]

Here is what I ve got so far : http://jsfiddle.net/skeletorkun/grn5o39e/1/

```
$(function () {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            size: '100%',
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };


    // The RPM gauge
    $('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'sth'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'RPM',
            data: [92],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>'

            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
            }
        }]

    }));




});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can realise that by solid-gauge and set a correct angles in pane.

```
pane: {
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e76o9otk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) suitable for you ?

This was made with div elements only, so very easy to customize and flexible to use.

For more details check the [**demos**](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) page.

### Demo on [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/utqgufx0/7/) same as your requirement